# Photoshop: shadow in flat ui?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am learning on a PSD file, the final picture like below, I really want to know how to make such a shadow effect.

[image]

I hidden all the above layer, and the shadow layer is this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do it?? I have this question for days, I asked in other place, but nobody answer my question.

Comment: Try searching for "extrude", which is what I would call this instead of a shadow

Comment: @JohnB thanks!! that is the answer I am looking for!